# Auto layout 3.5 - 4 inch screen as well as ipad mini to normal?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, autolayout

I know to go from the 3.5-4 inch screen with the app you create you have to use auto layout to make it nice on both screens. I was wondering if you had to do the same for the ipad mini - ipad? When i go into the attributes inspector there is no ipad mini choice on the view controller like there is for the 3.5 inch display. With the ipad story board is it a one size fits all type of thing or should I still use auto layout?

Thanks
Shen Hutah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for resizing with the 3.5-4 inch screens is due to a changed aspect ratio.  With iPad and iPad mini, they have the same aspect ratio (4:3), so the screens are functionally the same.  Unless you're altering the view based on autorotation, there's technically no need to use autolayout.